# Azure Function Output Service Bus Binding From Timer trigger

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs

I am running Visual Studio 2017 Preview and running the function code locally and I am using the out of the box Azure Function project template. I'm trying to have an Azure Function triggered by a timer send a message to a Service Bus queue using an output binding but it looks like the WebJob SDK can't bind the output to a string type.

**Binding**

```
 "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "serviceBus",
      "name": "msg",
      "queueName": "myqueue",
      "connection": "ServiceBusQueue",
      "accessRights": "manage",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
```

**Timer Function**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

namespace MyFunctionApp
{
    public static class TimerTrigger
    {
        [FunctionName("TimerTriggerCSharp")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("1 * * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log, out string msg)
        {
            log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            msg = "Hello!";
        }
    }
}
```

**Error Message**

> TimerTriggerCSharp: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing
>   method 'Functions.TimerTriggerCSharp'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host:
>   Cannot bind parameter 'msg' to type String&. Make sure the parameter
>   Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions
>   (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the
>   registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g.
>   config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.).

Am I missing a step in the setup, or does the Service Bus binding really not support a string for an `out` parameter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the binding attributes for `ServiceBus`.  I've only used the `ICollector<T>` types rather than an `out string` but it shouldn't matter either way.

```
[FunctionName("TimerTriggerCSharp")]
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer,
                       TraceWriter log,
                       [ServiceBus("%QueueName%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection", EntityType = Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.EntityType.Queue)] out string msg)
{
   msg = "My message";
}
```

To run locally with the VS2017 Preview tooling you will also need the following local settings defined in `local.settings.json` to match up with your `ServiceBus` attribute.

```
{
  "Values": {
     "ServiceBusConnection" : "Endpoint=sb://.....your connection",
     "QueueName": "my-service-bus-queue
   }
}
```

Comment: What reference you are using to get ServiceBus?